# Obtenção de Resto de um Ponto Flutuante

Tags: c

Eu tenho uma duvida em relação a isso.

Digamos que eu tenha um ponto flutuante, com o valor 1.13 ( Minutos.Segundos )
Como que eu faço, para obter o resto ( 13 ) do ponto flutuante?

Minutos . Segundos ( Resto )
   1    .   13

Como faço pra obter o 13 do ponto flutuante?

Answer (score 3):

Três formas:

```
#include <math.h>

double a=1.13;

// -> Forma 1
double f1 = a - ((long) a);

// -> Forma 2
double temp;
double f2 = modf(a, &temp);

// -> Forma 3
double f3 = remainder(a, 1.0);
```

Após executar:

```
f1 = 0.130000
f2 = 0.130000
f3 = 0.130000
```

Multiplicando o resultado por 100.0, por exemplo, você obtém o 13.

fonte: [Extract fractional part of double *efficiently* in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589383/extract-fractional-part-of-double-efficiently-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer um **cast** para obter o valor inteiro de `1.13` que é `1`, em seguia basta fazer esta equação: `partedecimal = valordouble - parteinteira` para obter o valor `0.13`, ou seja, sua parte decimal.

Veja a adaptação:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double obter_parte_decimal(double);

int main(void)
{
    printf("\nParte decimal de 1.13 = %f", obter_parte_decimal(1.13)); /*O valor que vc deseja obter.*/
    printf("\nParte decimal de 1.23 = %f", obter_parte_decimal(1.23));
    printf("\nParte decimal de 2.19 = %f", obter_parte_decimal(2.19));

    return 0;
}

double obter_parte_decimal(double valor)
{
    return valor - (int)valor;
}
```

Saída:

> Parte decimal de 1.13 = 0.130000
>   Parte decimal de 1.23 = 0.230000
>   Parte decimal de 2.19 = 0.190000

Criei a função `obter_parte_decimal` para alcançar o objetivo e retornar a parte decimal, cujo a sua assinatura é `double obter_parte_decimal(double);` desta forma você pode tirar um melhor proveito dela.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499939/extract-decimal-part-from-a-floating-point-number-in-c

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <math.h>

double x = 1.13;
double resto = floor((x - floor(x)) * 100);
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <== 0.13
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

/*Programa que separa as partes real e inteira de um valor real.*/

int main()
{
   float num = 4.13;
   float parteDec = 0;
   int   parteInt = 0;

   parteInt = num;
   parteDec = num - parteInt;

   printf("Parte inteira %i\n",parteInt); //Saída = 4
   printf("Parte decimal %g\n",parteDec); //Saída = 0.13
}
```